# Asset path '/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar' does not exist or contains no resources

Tags: android, android-maps

I have an app which uses google map. Google map is used on splash screen of the app, but as i run my app, it crashes and the first message that is shown in log cat is

```
Asset path '/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
```

Below is my complete logcat trace for reference.

```
11-05 18:04:53.920: W/ResourcesManager(15613): Asset path '/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
11-05 18:04:53.948: I/art(15613): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.it.customer.BaseActivity>
11-05 18:04:53.948: I/art(15613): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.it.customer.BaseActivity>
11-05 18:04:53.955: I/art(15613): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.it.customer.GetGCMID>
11-05 18:04:53.955: I/art(15613): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.it.customer.GetGCMID>
11-05 18:04:53.956: I/art(15613): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.it.customer.Splash>
11-05 18:04:53.957: D/AndroidRuntime(15613): Shutting down VM
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613): Process: com.it.customer, PID: 15613
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.it.customer/com.it.customer.Splash}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.it.customer.Splash" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.it.customer-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.it.customer.Splash" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.it.customer-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1088)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):    ... 10 more
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.it.customer.Splash
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):        ... 14 more
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.it.customer.Splash
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):        ... 13 more
11-05 18:04:53.959: E/AndroidRuntime(15613):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

**Here is my Android manifest file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.it.customer"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"


      android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <permission
        android:name="com.it.customer.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.it.customer.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <!-- for Samsung -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE" />

    <!-- for htc -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT" />

    <!-- for sony -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE" />

    <!-- for apex -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT" />
    <!-- for solid -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.it.customer.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.it.customer.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>



    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomAppThemeWithTab" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.it.customer.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.it.customer.CustomCamera"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.it.customer.RotatePicture"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.it.customer.Tutorial"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.it.customer.TermsAndConditions"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.it.customer.ContactUsWebView"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.it.customer.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MyCustomAppThemeWithTab"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.it.customer.Login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MyCustomAppThemeWithTab"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.it.customer.SignUp"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MyCustomAppThemeWithTab"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.it.customer.VerifyMobile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MyCustomAppThemeWithTab" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.it.customer.ForgotPassword"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MyCustomAppThemeWithTab" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.it.customer.ChangeLocationMap"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MyCustomAppThemeWithTab" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.it.customer.scanner.SimpleScannerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MyCustomAppThemeWithTab" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.it.customer.NotificationDialog"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/fb_app_id" />
         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAvnv69B_u2xesrzaBxU4_qczOAFWSFKPw" /> 
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAvnv69B_u2xesrzaBxU4_qczOAFWSFKPw" />

        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="true" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.it.customer" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.it.customer.utils.NodeJSConnectionService" />
        <service android:name="com.it.customer.GCMIntentService" >
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: did you add com.google.android.geo.API_KEY?

Comment: Hii, rajen yes i have added that in Androidmanifest.xml file like this <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAvnv69B_u2xesrzaBxU4_qczOAFWSFKPw" />

Comment: please share your android manifest

Comment: one question ..is the Api value added here in geo should be same with the Api key added in maps.v2.API_KEY

Comment: yes and also the apk u r installing should be signed with same certificate. i would suggest you to check google docs for this.

Comment: Hii, Rajen i have updated my question and posted my complete android manifest file .

Comment: Hii, Rajen please help me out .I have posted Android manifest file

Comment: http://umut.tekguc.info/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step

Comment: I have checked this "
umut.tekguc.info/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step" and followed step by step but still not able to get the desired result .It looks like i have tried everything but all in vain...

Comment: your logcat also says com.it.customer.Splash class not found this is the main issue it seems to be.

Comment: i dont know why this issue is appearing even though com.it.cutomer.Splash exists there !

Comment: Hii, Is any more details required from me regarding this issue ?. I am ready to share more information but i want to get rid of this issue because it is the entry point of my app. My app crashes as soon as it launches the splash screen.

Comment: me also facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Gradle files have no error, no missing or mismatch version numbers in compilations.

In my case, I had the similar problem with

```
 dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.2.0'
  provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:1.0.0'
 }
```

So provided wearable version and wearable compilation were not the same. Fixed it by changing `provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:1.0.0'` to `provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.1'`. So error is gone and I was able to install the application.